# Why `struct` unconstrained method fails to accept `null` as `T?` parameter

Tags: c#, compiler, null

Considering example below, one observe that for `reference type` argument is successfully understood as `nullable` parameter. For `value type` conversion to `T?/Nullable<T>` fails.

```csharp
T Method<T> ( T? t )
{
  // Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from '<null>' to 'float'
  float f1 = Method<float> (null);
  // ⇑⇑ float <float>(float) ⇑⇑

  // Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float?' to 'float'
  float f2 = Method<float> ((float?) null);
  // ⇑⇑ float <float>(float) ⇑⇑

  object? o1 = Method<object> (null);
  // ⇑⇑ object <object>(object?) ⇑⇑
  object o2  = Method<object> ((object?) null);
  // ⇑⇑ object <object>(object?) ⇑⇑

  return t;
}
```

Comments show resolved method signature. For `value type` `?` notion is completely ignored. That prevents `null` usage on input.

It is not so obvious what prevents compiler in understanding when `T?` should be understood as notion and when as declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signature is definitively unique so it cannot represent 2 overloads at once.

Signature

```csharp
T Method<T> ( T? t ) { … }
```

cannot be understand

```csharp
T Method<T> ( T? t ) { … } // where T is any reference type
```

and

```csharp
T Method<T> ( Nullable<T> t ) { … }
```

**at once**.

---

So it is chosen to go with `nullable-annotated` `reference type`.

```csharp
#nullable enable
void Method<T> ( T? t )
{
  Method<int> (9);      
}
#nullable disable
```

**IL**

```
.method /* 0600002A */ private hidebysig 
    instance void Method<T> (
        !!T t
    ) cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute::.ctor(uint8) = (
        01 00 02 00 00
    )
    …
```

`NullableContextAttribute` serves compiler *null state* analysis of *reference types*.

---

**Thoughts**

1. If `T?` declared `Nullable<T>` and `T` declared `Nullable<U>`, then `T` would be of type `Nullable<Nullable<U>`. That is prohibited.
2. If `T?` declared `Nullable<T>` and `T` was not `Nullable<U>`, then it would break generic method declaration since `Nullable<T>` and `T` are different types.

---

`struct` constraint squashes all problems making moderate, flat solution to problem.

Comment: NOTE: If you add a `where T:Object` then T is always a reference object so the `T?` can be supported.  That prevents the struct from using any instance where T itself is a struct.

Comment: Usually `class` is used for this purpose.

Answer (score 7):

A reference type parameter compiles to machine code that passes the value of a pointer to the passed variable to the subroutine, and all accesses in the subroutine implicitly dereference this pointer.

For a value type parameter, the computer has to pass the value itself (in a register, on the stack or a similar type of storage), but an unset nullable type *has* no representation in bits. Even "all-0" is most often wrong; a numeric value of 0 is very different from one that isn't defined. Therefore, instead of including super-special logic just for this not very useful use case, most compilers simply forbid it.

Comment: I edited my question since I asked something slightly different. Of  your answer only the part *Therefore, instead of including super-special logic just for this not very useful use case, most compilers simply forbid it.* is relevant for me.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift, when T is a type, “nullable T”  is a new type that needs one bit more for storage before optimisation. As an optimisation, for types where “all bits zero” is not valid, “all bits zero” is used to represent nil, otherwise it must be some extra bit. Lucky enough, that includes all pointers so nullable pointers don’t take more space.

Passing nullable values in Swift is no problem. A nullable 64 bit Int requires 65 bits, so will in practice use 128 bits. So it’s just a 128 bit value being passed. Reference values basically pass a reference (a pointer) by value.

And for example nullable Int is indeed very useful - for example a scanner parsing an int returns a nullable int, with nil on error.

Comment: "where “all bits zero” is not valid, “all bits zero” is used to represent nil" Not quite. Any uninhabited bit pattern (rust calls this a "niche") can be used. For example, nil optional `Bool` is modelled by `0b10`. You can see this with `unsafeBitCast(nil as Bool?, to: UInt8.self)`

Comment: I didn’t know the exact rules - the one that allows nullable pointers without extra data is the most important one. Since nullable things are just a clever enum with syntactic sugar, I wonder what other tricks the compiler uses for other enums. Say an enum with variants “nil”, “unknown”, “not read yet” and “known” with an actual value.

Comment: I haven't looked at the implementation myself, I would try to avoid baking in any special behaviour towards references types. I would aim to express the set of occupied values (all possible pointers) and all unoccopied values (invalid pointers), and feed that into a more generic niche-finding/exploiting mechanism.

Comment: I was playing around with this, and it turns out that you can fit a *lot* of enum cases into an enum that stores a non-nullable reference in an associated value. Try `enum E<T: AnyObject> { case reference(T), a, b, c, ... } ; print(MemoryLayout<E<C>>.size)`. I could add at least 524,288 such cases, while still keeping `E<C>` to 8 bytes.

Comment: Question was specifically about rules that applies to C# language. So providing general or specific answer is just right. Eccentric details of _Swift_ does not fit.

Comment: Ucho What’s wrong with learning, broadening your horizons? What are the bets that details will move to other languages? Instead of moaning like you, I used the opportunity to learn things I didn’t know.

Comment: And C# is just a tag. The title and the question count.

Comment: Hi Alexander, just remembered that at least on 64Bit MacOS and iOS the highest 32 bits of a pointer are never zero. On the other hand, Objective C uses “tagged pointers” that are not real pointers for a very small number of classes, for example NSNumber. Interesting.

Comment: gnasher729 You’re twit. I want to deepen my .NET/C# knowledge. Widening general knowledge with details of full-scale language like Swift definitely is is directly counterproductive.